# How to add a shadow to the inside bottom edge of a collection view cell? swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I'd like to create a collectionViewCell, I currently have a UIImageView taking up the entire contentView of the cell but would like to add a shadow to the bottom of the image (starting at the bottom edge going towards the middle of the cell). How would I go about doing this in swift 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yourCollectionViewCell.layer.masksToBounds = false
yourCollectionViewCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
yourCollectionViewCell.layer.borderWidth = 7.0
yourCollectionViewCell.layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
yourCollectionViewCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75
yourCollectionViewCell.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
yourCollectionViewCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
yourCollectionViewCell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath.init(rect: yourCollectionViewCell.bounds).cgPath
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

This is my example. you try customize as you like.

Comment: thanks, this works great for adding a shadow to all of the edges, but how do I change the path to just the bottom edge, and change the direction of the shadow to "cast" over the content inside the collectionViewCell?

Comment: you try change shadowOffset for YourCollectionViewCell. Try this: 

yourCollectionViewCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: -15, height: 5

It might help you

Comment: When I write like this. I found it worked well for what you wanted: 

self.formView.layer.masksToBounds = false self.formView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75  self.formView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0  self.formView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: -15, height: 5)  self.formView.layer.shouldRasterize = true